# Pounds to kilo Ruby not working

Tags: ruby

So I'm fairly new to this, and I'm trying to make a program that takes pounds and converts it to kilos. Here's what I'm

```
print "Enter your mass in pounds"
pounds = gets.chomp
print pounds * 0.454
```

But for some reason all I get is `nil`. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Do as below:

```
print "Enter your mass in pounds"
pounds = gets.chomp.to_f
print pounds * 0.454
```

You are trying to multiply a string by a floating point number which would return an empty string, you should convert `pounds` to a numeric object (float) before multiplying

Comment: I would suggest using to_f instead of to_i, in the case where you want to convert 1.5kg to lbs (http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_f)

Answer (score 1):

`gets.chomp` got a string, convert it to an integer: `print pounds.to_i * 0.454`